# Call function after detecting iFrame has loaded, or after 3 second timeout

Tags: javascript, iframe, settimeout

I want to load a external URL in a hidden iframe on my web page.  I need to detect once the external URL has finished loading, and then call my Function MyFunct().  If the external URL takes longer than 3 seconds to load I need to timeout and call MyFunct()

Will the following code call my function MyFunct() either once the iframe has loaded or after 3 seconds because of the timeout ?

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('MyFrame');
iframe.src = "SomeRandonUrl";

iframe.onload = function () {
   setTimeout(MyFunct, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if it has loaded in a timeout event like the following.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('MyFrame');
iframe.src = "SomeRandonUrl";

iframe.onload = function () {
    if (iframe.src !== "about:blank")
        iframe.loaded = true; // set that it has loaded if not about:blank
}

setTimeout(function() {
    if (!iframe.loaded) { // if undefined or false valued
        alert('Timedout');
        // and then you can cancel it's loading setting another src for e.g
    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: If the timeout is reached, how can I prevent the iframe from continuing to load? I tried adding iframe.src = "about:blank"; before the alert('Timedout');, but still the iframe.loaded = true; was still reached

Comment: setting the src to "about:blank" will trigger the "onload" event. What you can do, is check if the src != "about:blank". I'll update the answer.
Or you can even set the `onload` event as null. `iframe.onload = null`;

Comment: Thanks, I went for setting iframe.onload = null;